# How to set up the Ibm Connector using python api ibm_db

Tags: python-3.x, db2

When I try to connect on the IBM DB2 AS400 through the python api "ibm_bd".

```
import ibm_db
connection = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=database;HOSTNAME=10.56.4.20;PORT=8476;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=passwd;", "", "")
```

I get this error message:

> SQLCODE=-30081n: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error
> has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".
> Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was
> detected: "10.16.1.10".  Communication function detecting the error:
> "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10060", "*", "*".
> SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: To connect to as400 (i series) with python, it is wiser to use the odbc driver that comes as an option with "IBM i access" product. You are using clidriver (which requires a license file otherwise it will fail to connect). However, the error message suggests that you are using the wrong port-number, or that a firewall is blocking the specifed port between your workstation and the as00.

Comment: Thank you, using odbc driver I solved my issue !